# Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread

Tags: java, android

Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread  please help. Im a beginner in android studio found these codes online but cant figured it out
I would really appreciate it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TableLayout table_layout;
    EditText firstname_et, lastname_et;
    Button addmem_btn;

    SQLController sqlcon;

    ProgressDialog PD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sqlcon = new SQLController(this);

        firstname_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fistname_et_id);
        lastname_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname_et_id);
        addmem_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addmem_btn_id);
        table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        BuildTable();

        addmem_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new MyAsync().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    private void BuildTable() {

        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry();

        int rows = c.getCount();
        int cols = c.getColumnCount();

        c.moveToFirst();

        // outer for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // inner for loop
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                tv.setText(c.getString(j));

                row.addView(tv);

            }

            c.moveToNext();

            table_layout.addView(row);

        }
        sqlcon.close();
    }

    private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            table_layout.removeAllViews();

            PD = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            PD.setMessage("Loading...");
            PD.setCancelable(false);
            PD.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            **String firstname = firstname_et.getText().toString();
            String lastname = lastname_et.getText().toString();**

            // inserting data
            sqlcon.open();
            sqlcon.insertData(firstname, lastname);
            // BuildTable();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            BuildTable();
            PD.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exact error or problem? please make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get values in `onPreExecute()` its UI thread not in background thread.

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String firstname,lastname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            table_layout.removeAllViews();

            PD = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            PD.setMessage("Loading...");
            PD.setCancelable(false);
            // get values here its UI thread 
            firstname = firstname_et.getText().toString();
            lastname = lastname_et.getText().toString();
            PD.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

           // **String firstname = firstname_et.getText().toString();
           // String lastname = lastname_et.getText().toString();**

            // inserting data
            sqlcon.open();
            sqlcon.insertData(firstname, lastname);
            // BuildTable();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            BuildTable();
            PD.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the UI thread from a background thread (your Async task) which you cannot do.

```
 String firstname = firstname_et.getText().toString();
            String lastname = lastname_et.getText().toString();
```

add theese lines in your UI thread not in async task

here is an example

```
  // ui thread 
    // call async task and send UI data
    new checkLogInDetails(editEmail.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString()).execute();

// you can change the params of async task as your requirement
 private class checkLogInDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        private final String userName;
        private final String password;

//create a constructor an access UI thread data
        public checkLogInDetails(String userName, String password) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;

        }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()...
```

Comment: Just make firstName and lastName class variables of MyAsync, and set them in onPreExecute()

Answer (score 0):

you can not use **getText** inside **AsyncTask**.
you have to pass the parameter like this :

> new MyAsync().execute(firstname_et.getText().toString(),lastname_et.getText().toString());

then in the async task yo have to change the error line to this :

> String firstname = (String) params[0];
>   String lastname = (String) params[1];

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
   String firstname;
    String secondname;    

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){ 
        firstname = firstname_et.getText().toString();
        lastname = lastname_et.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // inserting data
            sqlcon.open();
            sqlcon.insertData(firstname, lastname);
            // BuildTable();
            return null;
        }
```